# Upload array of pdf files and Images upload to server by using Alamofire multipartFormData with extra parameters in ios swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, alamofire

Upload  array of pdf files and Images upload to the server by using  Alamofire multipart form data with extra parameters in ios swift

post body :

let discount = ["widgetType":"FELLOWSHIP_DISCOUNT","type":"FELLOWSHIP","widgetId":1] as?  [String:Any] ?? [:]

```
    let parameters: [String: Any] =
        [
            "files":[imagesData],
            "discount": discount
    ]
```

Comment: let discount = ["widgetType":"FELLOWSHIP_DISCOUNT","type":"FELLOWSHIP","widgetId":1] as? [String:Any] ?? [:]

Comment: let parameters: [String: Any] =
        [
            "files":[imagesData],
            "discount": discount
    ]

Comment: please reply any one

Comment: Could you show your own attempts and show where it seems to fail?